# How is it possible to make a matrix with special random elements?

Tags: julia

is there any possibility in Julia to make a matrix with special random elements?
for example, a matrix which each row has random elements but every elements should repeat at least one time:

```
n = zeros(Int,3, 5)

    for i in indices(n, 1)

        for j in indices(n, 2)

            n[i,j]=rand(0:3)

        end

    end
 n=
3×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  1  1  2
 3  3  2  2  0
 3  2  1  0  0
```

but in second row, there is not  `1` . would you please help me how this matrix is made? 
Thanks.

Comment: It should be relatively easily done, but can you please specify what sampling model you expect (i.e. in mathematical terms) because there are many possibilities that could be used. For example it is not clear for me why you have a problem with the second row in your example but not with the first one.

Comment: I have problem in first one row also . it should have `0,3`. {0,1,2,3} are selected one time at least. as follow:
     `1  0  1  3  2;
      3  3  2  1  0;
      3  2  1  0  0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
using Random

function randfill!(m::AbstractMatrix, s::AbstractVector)
    n1 = length(s)
    n2 = size(m, 2)
    @assert n2 >= n1
    for i in 1:size(m,1)
        m[i, 1:n1] .= s
        for j in n1+1:n2
            m[i,j] = rand(s)
        end
        shuffle!(view(m, i, :))
    end
    m
end
```

Comment: I learnt lots of things that I didn't know before. Thanks very much @ Prof.Bogumił Kamiński